# getText of the JTextArea and increas the font size of the Strings inside

Tags: java, string, swing, jtextarea

Is it possible to getText of the JTextArea and then increase or decrease its font size? Just like in Microsoft, when you select a line or some words, by changing the value of font size you can increase/decrease its size.
The thing in my mind is;

```
JTextArea x = new JTextArea( "abcdefg" );
x.getText();
x.setLetterSize( 20 ); // I only want to increase the size of the String, I do not concern with style or font
```

So that the String looks bigger or smaller on my panel. Is there a way to create such a method?

Comment: (1-) Don't post multiple questions on the same topic If there is something you don't understand in your other question, then post a follow up question so all the information is contained in a single posting and everybody knows what has been suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The `getText()` function of `JTextArea` returns a `String` containing the contents. You cannot use the return value to modify the size of the text.

You can use `setFont(Font)` to set the display font. Here is an example:

```
x.setFont(new Font(Font.PLAIN, "Arial", 12)); // sets the font to Arial with a 12-pixel size
```